# Jquery extensions for asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Are there any jquery extensions available for asp.net mvc? I'm looking for adapters which can be used instead of having to write all javascripts manually. for instance: just include jqgrid script in the master page, call CreateGrid extension metod to define the grid and return a JqGridActionResult from an action to populate it.

I found the following project but it seems dead:
http://jmvcui.codeplex.com/

and then GPL:d telerik controls:
http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Telerik controls are awesome, and are also available for download on their telerik.com site.  THey give you script registration features, but there isn't anything there to build or utilize the type of setup you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The jqGrid folks have [a commercial component for MVC](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx). Seems kind of code-heavy to me, though. I'm probably going to write my own to use default templated views instead.